# Issue with metrics which calculates my N-1 values, when adding date or week attributes to my cube in Microstrategy

Tags: data-structures, data-modeling, microstrategy

I have a cube that contains several attributes and metrics, including a metrics that calculates quantity and values of this year and last year. The metrics works perfectly when I have year and month as attributes of time, but when I'm adding date or week attributes to my cube, the metric does not work correctly.

Could you please help me to investigate this issue and find a solution? Thank you

I have tried checking the data type, attribute relationships, aggregation settings, and data for the date and week attributes, but I have not been able to solve the problem. I am not sure if there is an issue with my data model or cube design that is causing the problem.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95zxl.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]